# RDS Session Collections / Farms / Administration / Setup when there is a master / slave-type domain and which account to use?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I'm setting up RDS Session Collections in dedicated domains. 
We have our top level domain COMPANY.COM which is our master domain for administering all others. 
CLIENT.COMPANY.COM is the dedicated sub/slave domain being used for RDS remote apps.

We have a one-way trust system where we can authenticate with our COMPANY.COM domain admin accounts as local admins on CLIENT.COMPANY.COM VMs. I want to set up RDS for CLIENT.COMPANY.COM to use but I noticed that if I create a session collection with either my COMPANY.COM domain admin account or the CLIENT.COMPANY.COM domain admin account I can only administer RDS with that specific account and not the other (if that makes sense?)

RDS apps will be consumed by CLIENT.COMPANY.COM domain users.

Is it best practise to create the rds deployment / session collection etc with my COMPANY.COM domain admin account or my CLIENT.COMPANY.COM domain admin account?

Comment: I'm thinking it should all be created under CLIENT.COMPANY.COM but just wanted clarification